# How do I get my applications back after using the * command deletes them all?

Tags: command-line, data-recovery, recovery-mode

I used this command "sudo apt-get purge bluez* bluetooth" to get rid of bluetooth but I realized that the * command is dangerous and will get rid of all the other applications and programs and now I am missing whole lot of programs on the sidebar and can no longer access them. How can I get them back?

Comment: If you ran what you show, you will only have deleted packages whose name starts with `bluez`, what else is missing? Did you perhaps run `sdo apt-get purge bluez * bluetooth` instead? (note the space before and after the `*`).

Answer (score 1):

You can install the applications individually.  There are lots of components that are installed by default that you'll never have need for.  So if you don't have something specific you wish to install, you might be just as well without it.

You can look at your apt-get log and see which files your purged and individually install them.

the apt-get history log:

```
tac /var/log/dpkg.log | less
```

cli to see recent purged packages:

```
tac /var/log/dpkg.log | egrep purge | less
```